# How can I apply this function on every file in R?

Tags: r

I have files named `P1.txt P2.txt ........P100.txt`. 
And I want to do apply the following functions on each of these files:

```
temp <- P1.txt
colnames(temp) <- c("a","b")
temp <- aggregate(count~a+b,transform(temp,a=pmin(a,b), b=pmax(a,b), count=1),sum)
colnames(temp) <- c("V1","V2","V3")
P1.txt <- temp
```

How can I automate this for each of these files? 
I was able to come up with the `paste0("P",i,".txt") where i will vary from 1 to 100 but I don't know how to assign it again? Thanks!

Edit: The individual files are dataframes containing two columns initially and 1000's of rows.
Sample: (P1.txt)

```
1 2
3 4
4 2
4 5
....
```

Comment: Please provide information about the structure of the files.

Answer (score 1):

Only a partial answer since you haven't given us the structure of the files...

If you want to read in these files and write them out, then you will need to explicitly do this with for instance `read.csv()`  and `write.csv()`.  Then you can just:

```
for(i in 1:100) {
  fnam <- paste('P', i, '.txt', sep='')
  temp <- read.csv(fnam, header=FALSE)
  # manipulate the contents...
  colnames(temp) <- c("a", "b")
  temp <- aggregate(count ~ a + b,
                    transform(temp, a = pmin(a, b), b = pmax(a, b), count = 1), 
                    sum)
  colnames(temp) <- c("V1", "V2", "V3")
  # save the results
  write.csv(temp, fnam, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
}
```

However, beware of using this before verifying its' correctness as you risk over-writing your P1..P100.txt files!

Comment: I have added the structure of files.

Comment: This doesn't overwrite the files. That is what I wanted to do but it didn't happen. I used `write.table(temp,fnam)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach.

```
# generate list of files
files <- list.files(pattern = "^P\\d+\\.txt$")

for (file in files) {
  temp <- read.table(file)
  colnames(temp) <- c("a", "b")
  temp <- aggregate(count ~ a + b,
                    transform(temp, a = pmin(a, b), b = pmax(a, b), count = 1), 
                    sum)
  colnames(temp) <- c("V1", "V2", "V3")
  write.table(temp, file, row.names = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't overwrite the files named `P1.txt...P100.txt` as well.

Comment: It still doesn't overwrite the files. This is the problem.

Comment: @chanchong Do you have the permission to overwrite the files?

Comment: I am able to overwrite them when I am executing them on a single file.

Comment: can yo please help me?

Comment: I dont receive an error message. The files dont get overwritten. The value of variable temp changes but the files dont change.

Comment: @chanchong What happens if you save it with different filename.

Comment: I want to overwrite the files with the new values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62482/discussion-between-chan-chong-and-sven-hohenstein).